# Why is $E(\min(A, B)) < \min(E(A), E(B))$?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent, positive random variables. Why must $E(\min(A, B)) < \min(E(A), E(B))$, where $\min(X, Y)$ is the minimum of $X$ and $Y$?

I would think the opposite, that $E(A, B) > \min(E(A), E(B))$ because $E(\min(A, B))$ weights all possible values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\min(A,B) \le A$, so $E[\min(A,B)] \le E[A]$.  Similarly $E[\min(A,B)] \le E[B]$.
Thus $E[\min(A,B)] \le \min(E[A],E[B])$.

But the statement with $<$ is not true.  For example, if  $A < B$ in all outcomes, $\min(A,B) = A$ and
$E[\min(A,B)] = E[A] = \min(E[A],E[B])$.

Comment: This indicates that if F is a function, then F(min(a, b))≤min(F(a), F(b)).  So one could respond to the question by saying "because E is a function."

Comment: Or rather, because $E$ is a nondecreasing function.

Answer (score 2):

Robert's answer is great, but to gain some more intuition, imagine that the expected value behaves like a mean and compare the following inequalities.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \min(A,B) &\leq \min(\mathbb{E} A, \mathbb{E} B) \\ \\
\frac{\min(a_1,b_1) + \min(a_2,b_2)}{2} &\leq \min\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}, \frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Cheers!